# Proving Fibonacci sum with induction

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

Let the Fibonacci sequence be defined as $f_1 = f_2 = 1$ and $f_n = f_{n-1} + f_{n-2}$

Prove that $f_1f_2+f_2f_3+f_3f_4+...+f_{2n-1}f_{2n}+f_{2n}f_{2n+1} = f^2_{2n+1} - 1$

I was able to verify that the claim holds for $n=1$, since $(1)(1)+(1)(2) = 2^2 - 1$

Now, assuming that the claim is true for every $n=k$, it should be sufficient to prove by checking if $n=k+1$ also is true.

$f_1f_2+f_2f_3+...+f_{2k-1}f_{2k}+f_{2k}f_{2k+1}+f_{2(k+1)}f_{2(k+1)+1}$

$ f^2_{2k+1} - 1 +f_{2(k+1)}f_{2(k+1)+1}$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Sure. Should I edit the question or just add a comment?

Comment: Editing the question seems to be the convention here (someone correct me if I am wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

If the statement holds for $n$, then
$f_1f_2 + \dots + f_{2n}f_{2n+1}+ f_{2n+1}f_{2n+2}+f_{2n+2}f_{2n+3}= (\boxed{f_{2n+1}^2}-1) +\boxed{f_{2n+1}f_{2n+2}}+f_{2n+2}f_{2n+3}= f_{2n+1}\underbrace{(f_{2n+1} + f_{2n+2})}_{=\text{what is it?}} + f_{2n+2}f_{2n+3} -1 = \dots \text{(similar step)} = f_{2n+3}^2-1.$

Answer (score 2):

Your error is that for increasing $k$ by $1$, you should have two new terms.
Then $$f^2_{2k+1}-1+f_{2k+1}f_{2k+2}+f_{2k+2}f_{2k+3}=f_{2k+1}(f_{2k+1}+f_{2k+2})+f_{2k+2}f_{2k+3}-1\\=f_{2k+1}f_{2k+3}+f_{2k+2}f_{2k+3}-1=f_{2k+3}(f_{2k+1}+f_{2k+2})-1=f_{2k+3}^2-1$$